# Unable to Retrieve Objects from Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firebase and Kotlin, and am trying to make an application with it. I have a data class named Announcements, and I had saved the data for Announcements in Firestore. However, when I wanted to retrieve my data from Firestore, it keeps giving me the following error:

```
2019-10-09 03:14:13.016 14552-14552/com.example.finalyearproject W/Firestore: (21.1.1) [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for Content found on class com.example.finalyearproject.Announcement
2019-10-09 03:14:13.017 14552-14552/com.example.finalyearproject W/Firestore: (21.1.1) [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for Title found on class com.example.finalyearproject.Announcement
2019-10-09 03:14:13.017 14552-14552/com.example.finalyearproject W/Firestore: (21.1.1) [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for Id found on class com.example.finalyearproject.Announcement
2019-10-09 03:14:13.018 14552-14552/com.example.finalyearproject W/Firestore: (21.1.1) [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for Date found on class com.example.finalyearproject.Announcement
```

Following is my codes:

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val announcement = Announcement(_aTitle = "Hello Everyone", _aContent = "A new age begins.", _aDate = Date())
announcement.writeToDatabase()

val mAnnouncements: ArrayList<Announcement> = ArrayList()

db.collection(Announcement.ANNOUNCEMENT_COLLECTION).get().addOnSuccessListener {
            mAnnouncements.addAll(it.toObjects(Announcement::class.java))
}
```

Announcement Class:

```
class Announcement(_aId: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(), _aTitle: String = " ", _aContent: String = " ", _aDate: Date = Date()) {

    var aId = _aId
    var aTitle = _aTitle
    var aContent = _aContent
    var aDate = _aDate

    fun writeToDatabase() {

        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        val write = hashMapOf(
            ANNOUNCEMENT_ID to this.aId,
            ANNOUNCEMENT_TITLE to this.aTitle,
            ANNOUNCEMENT_CONTENT to this.aContent,
            ANNOUNCEMENT_DATE to this.aDate
        )

        db.collection(ANNOUNCEMENT_COLLECTION).document(this.aId.toString()).set(write).addOnSuccessListener { Log.d("Success", "Success") }


    }

    companion object {
        const val ANNOUNCEMENT_COLLECTION = "announcement"
        const val ANNOUNCEMENT_ID = "Id"
        const val ANNOUNCEMENT_TITLE = "Title"
        const val ANNOUNCEMENT_CONTENT = "Content"
        const val ANNOUNCEMENT_DATE = "Date"
    }
}
```

I had tried to search for answers, but seems like there is no suitable answer in Kotlin. I had tried to add custom getter and setter for each variable, but still it does not works.

Please help if anyone is able to solve my questions. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Kotlin data class with [documentSnapshot.toObject](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#toObject(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)), you're going to have to make each field of the data class a nullable `var`. The Firestore SDK doesn't know how to map document fields into data class constructor argument.  If the fields are nullable `val`, then the Kotlin compiler will create getters and setters for each field so they can be discovered and called by the Firestore SDK.

If you want a proper immutable data class with `val` fields, you're going to have to manually read each field out of the document, and call the data class constructor yourself.